# memory leak when just newing and Disposing Gtk.Window

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Just creating and disposing of a Gtk.Window object seems to cause a memory leak.

For example the following code example quickly takes greater than 1GB, (as shown by Linux System Monitor - both VM and Resident Memory a few seconds later):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10485760; i++)
  new Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.Popup).Dispose();
```

This GTK FAQ page refers to the need to call ref + sink [gtk faq (1.5)](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-question-index.html)

but I've tried both

```
var window = new Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.Popup).Ref().Sink(); 
window.Unref();
window.Destroy();
```

and

```
new Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.Popup).Destroy();
```

and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Does anyone know what one is mean to do to prevent memory leaks in this use case?

Comment: You are putting a lot of pressure on the GC with those allocations.  Do you really need to create 10485760 instances of a Gtk.Window?

Comment: It was just a test program, in the real program a lot less get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah - answering my own question.

This seems to prevent memory leaks.

```
var window = new Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.Popup);
window.Destroy();
window.Dispose();
```

Comment: I guess you missed the part where it said "If GtkFoo isn't a toplevel window, then ..." which means that the window you were creating wasn't a `toplevel window`

Comment: no I read that part, I just initially didn't test both Dispose and Destroy. Which the FAQ didn't have of course because its not a Gtk# FAQ. But yes it isn't a top level window. (I actually embedd the window into a winform's form.)